# Fix potential memory leak in ARC

Tags: ios, singleton, automatic-ref-counting

The following singleton class (SharedManager) helper method might be causing a retain cycle. Getting warnings in static analyzer: "Potential leak of an object allocated at line ..." How can I fix?

I did try making ivar uuid __weak but warning still appears when I analyze.

```
    NSString  *__weak uuid =  (__bridge NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject);
```

Thanks

Being called in the class like so:

```
myUUID = [SharedManager generateUUID];



+ (NSString *)generateUUID
{

 CFUUIDRef uuidObject = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
 NSString  *uuid =  (__bridge NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject);
CFRelease(uuidObject);

  return uuid;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString  *uuid =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject);
```

Does that remove the warning?

Comment: Peter, Yes, it did. Thanks. Need to understand what __bridge_transfer is all about.

Comment: Take a look at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts

Comment: `NSString *CFUUID = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault));` -- Analyzer is whining about a potential leak. Is it just a bug I can't fix? JOG's answer works, but a single line is so much cleaner and nicer to look at.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to release them:

```
- (NSString *) uuid
{
    CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef uuidStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidRef);
    CFRelease(uuidRef);
    NSString *uuid = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)
    uuidStringRef];
    CFRelease(uuidStringRef);
    return uuid;
}
```

<sub>Source: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/217665-how-to-create-guid.html</sub>