# CFUUID - creating ONCE & using throughout life of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I wrote these lines in my code:

```
CFUUIDRef identifier = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
NSString *identifierString = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, identifier);
NSLog(@"%@",identifierString);
[self setValue:identifierString forKey:kParamNameDeviceId];
```

But these lines are getting called every time when the app launches.

Now my question is, how can the following be achieved?

- Create CFUUID.
- Store it in some variable in such a way that, when next time my app starts, it should not create a new CFUUID. It should look for the previously created CFUUID and return it.

In short, I want a CFUUID be created ONCE and used throughout the life of the app (till it gets uninstalled).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create once. Add it in NSUSerDefaults and check whether you have a UUID stored already before creating one. Simple Pseudo code,

```
    NSString *CFUUID = nil;

if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UUID"]) {
    //create CFUUDID.

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:CFUUID forKey:@"UUID"];

}
else
{
    CFUUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UUID"];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

easiest way is to store it in [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSString *identifierString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myID"];
if (!identifierString) {
    CFUUIDRef identifier = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    identifierString = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, identifier);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:identifierString forKey:@"myID"];
}
NSLog(@"%@",identifierString);
/* ... */
```

Comment: Don't forget that it should be released: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778182/fix-potential-memory-leak-in-arc/10143804#10143804

Answer (score 3):

If you are storing identifier on server to keep track of important information regarding unique user than i suggest you store **identifierString** in "KeyChain" which keeps that identifier even if you application has been deleted by user.

**NSUserDefaults** keep data until app is deleted. **Keychain** keeps data even if app is deleted.

I had similar case so this might help if your case is equivalent to mine.